# How to convert logical columns to double in MATLAB table

Tags: matlab, casting

For my task I need to convert all logical columns in a table to double. The table is sorted so I want to keep the order of columns.

Here is a mini example:

```
SomeString={'one';'two';'three'}
SomeNumbers={1;2;3}
SomeLogicals=[true; false; true]
T=table(SomeString, SomeNumbers, SomeLogicals)

T(:,vartype('logical'))=cell2table(cellfun(@double,table2cell(T(:,vartype('logical'))),'uniformOutput',false))
```

Why are the columns still logical?

```
T(:,vartype('logical'))

  3×1 table

    SomeLogicals
    ________

       true     
       false    
       true
```

And how can I convert them?

Comment: Does this do what you want, `T.SomeLogicals = double(T.SomeLogicals)`?

Comment: For one column, yes. But I don't want to type this for all my 50 columns. Also the column name changes.

Comment: I mean it the column name changes as I'm reading in different tables with different column names. 
Maybe I could try to identify the logical column names and then create a call with eval(sprintf(...)) but thats pretty ugly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your reply to my comment, this should do what you want

```
logicalColumns = T.Properties.VariableNames(cellfun(@(x) islogical(T.(x)), T.Properties.VariableNames));
for c = 1:length(logicalColumns)
  T.(logicalColumns{c}) = double(T.(logicalColumns{c}));
end
```

Here we get the names of the columns which contain logical values and then iterate over these columns setting them to double values of `1` or `0` for `true` and `false`.

Comment: Welcome! Glad it worked. Tables aren't as nicely supported as they should be in Matlab.